# How to loop through JSON from JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, django-models

I requested some data from my django server. Then I used JSON.parse to deserialized the data into a JSON object.I want to loop through each object  field attribute and call the function `createDiv` on each of them.

```
  function load_blog(){

  let start_blog = 0
  let end_blog = 4

  fetch(`/blog/?start=${start_blog}&end_blog=${end_blog}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json_blogs => {
    var jsblog = JSON.parse(json_blogs)
    jsblog.fields.forEach()

  })
}
```

This is how my data looks after using JSON.parse
[image]

I would like to use the function on each `field` dict.However I'm getting this error:

```
jsblog.fields is undefined
```

And I'm clearly seeing fields from the console. So could anyone assist me?

Comment: Your `jsblog` is an array of four objects, each one containing a property named `fields`, whose value is itself an object. Therefore, `jsblog.fields` is undefined, as expected. What you have to do is iterate over the array (for instance, `jsblog.forEach(o => { doSomethingWith(o.fields); })`, doing whatever you want with each `fields` property inside the loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: You are already calling `response.json()`. Why are you parsing again with `JSON.parse`?

Comment: I wasn't getting the data in an array of objects before json.parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, if I'm right, `jsblog` is an array of Objects, right?

Thus if you want to iterate on `jsblog`, you might want to do that in this way: `jsblog.forEach(...)`.
Then in the callback, you can reference `fields` property of each object.

```js
jsblog.forEach(blogObject => console.log(blogObject.fields));
```

By `jsblog.fields`, you tried to access the property called `fields` of the array of objects, which shall be `undefined`. `jsblog` does not have `fields` property, but the children of `jsblog` do.